# How can I remove Signing certificates that appear in Xcode 11.5 and no longer have a private key?

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I remove Signing certificates that no longer have a private key?

Here's a view of what happens when I open Xcode and click Manage Certificates.  Are these stored on my machine or part of the developer account.

[image: OS]

I would like to remove all of these as none of them are valid. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Please note the version of XCode as I see other suggestions on the web but they refer to earlier versions of XCode and I think things change frequently.

Comment: They should be stored in **Keychain** on your Mac, so you can remove from there.

Comment: All of them say "Missing Private Key".  I could be wrong but I think that's because the keys are not stored on the Keychain.

Comment: There are certificate and private key pairs in Keychain, private key mains **.p12** version of related certificate. Did you check **My Certificates** section in Keychain app?

Comment: You are correct.  Can you add this as an answer so I can accept.  Also I have one more SO question and another I am just going to create.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693185/in-xcode-11-5-i-am-trying-to-download-profiles-needed-what-is-the-difference-b

Comment: Sure, i added now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certificate are stored in **Keychain** on your Mac, so you can remove from **My Certificates** section in Keychain.

Comment: I also have this question.  Maybe you can help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693185/in-xcode-11-5-i-am-trying-to-download-profiles-needed-what-is-the-difference-b

Comment: This question also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694441/how-can-i-set-up-another-user-to-be-able-to-develop-and-distribute-ios-apps-if-i

Comment: I have the same problem and this solution did not work ("My Certificates" is empty, but XCode still lists certificates with missing private keys).