# In Xcode 11.5, I am trying to download profiles needed. What is the difference between Agent and User on the Accounts screen?

Tags: ios, xcode

Here's the screen I refer to:

[image]

I would like to know.  Should I be downloading Manual profiles for the user or Agent and what is the difference between these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to register for Apple Developer Program

1. Enrol as an Individual
2. Enrol as an Organization

If you enrol as an individual you will be only seeing 1 option in Xcode Accounts screen with role "Agent"

if you enrol as an Organisation you will be seeing 2 options Xcode Accounts

- Your apple Id user with role as `User`
- Organisation Name (Registered with Apple Developer Program) and role will be your current logged in Apple Id user role for that Organisation.

In your case Developer Account is registered as an Organization and logged in Apple Id is Agent of the account. So If you wan't to download profiles or manage development or distribution certificates you must select your Organisation.

Answer (score 2):

See all roles here: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

For example Agent -

> ...the Team Agent role and Legal role are now called "Account Holder".

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the role here: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

- Agent is account holder who paid the enrollment fee
- User (Personal Team) is a free developer account, if you enroll as an Organisation or use a free account and invited to an organization you will see this