# How can I set up another user to be able to develop and distribute iOS apps if I have a key and profile?

Tags: ios, xcode

Here's what I have:

[image]

At the bottom are files on my hard disk.

What I would like to know is, can I somehow send these to another user so that user can be set up to develop locally and to distribute the app. If so, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as @Nahash to export and share with the other developer,

1. Select both - certificate and the private key in your keychain.
2. Open context menu by the "right click".
3. Tap "Export 2 items" and choose .p12 file.
4. Generate the secure password for the cert + key pair.
5. Share this file with your developer.

For the other developer to install those key make sure he navigate to terminal to where the pem key file actually is. Then use this command will add this key to his keychain, terminal may ask for private key password you need to share with him the password if you set a password while expoting

```
security import pub_key.pem -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Answer (score 1):

It's super easy to do:

1. Select both - certificate and the private key in your keychain.
2. Open context menu by the "right click".
3. Tap "Export 2 items" and choose .p12 file.
4. Generate the secure password for the cert + key pair.
5. Share this file with your developer.